# EF Core - Both relationships could use same property as foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an unusual situation, and I'm trying to figure out a way around it.  I'm making changes to an existing data model that I did not create, and I'm afraid that the changes might not be compatible.

I started with this model (paired down):

```
public class Invoice 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public decimal? SalesTaxAmount { get; set; }
    
    public List<InvoiceLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLineItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public InvoiceLineItemType LineItemType { get; set; }
    
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When an expense is associated to an invoice, a Line Item of type ExpenseLineItem is added to the Line Item collection.

When the database is created from this model, The InvoiceLineItem has a shadow foreign key back to the Invoice table that EF added by default (called InvoiceId), without any configuration in OnModelCreating.  This works fine, as expected.  The Expense table has a nullable InvoiceId column that's not a foreign key.  To be honest, I'm not sure why this is the case, as I didn't create it.

I have a new requirement where I need to link individual costs on the invoice to the entities that represenst those costs.  This means I need to:

1. Add a new entity that represents an associated cost - think bank account entry, like this:

```
    public class Entry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public InvoiceLineItem LineItem { get; set; }   
    }
```

2. Link Expense entity to the line item created when it's added to the invoice.
3. Link that line item to the new Entry entity.
4. Tie the Sales Tax amount to an Entry entity.  I thought about making this an InvoiceLineItem property on the Invoice itself, and having the SalesTaxAmount getters/setters reach into that property = something like:

```
    public class Invoice 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public decimal? SalesTaxAmount      
        { 
            get => salesTax?.Amount ?? 0;
            set
            {
                SetupSalesTax(); 
                salesTax.Amount = value;
            }
        }
        
        public InvoiceLineItem SalesTax
        {
            get
            {
                return salesTax is null ? null : new InvoiceLineItem // Return a copy
                {
                    Id = salesTax.Id,
                    Amount = salesTax.Amount
                    InvoiceLineItemType = Helpers.InvoiceLineItemType.Tax,
                    UnitPrice = salesTax.UnitPrice
                 };
             }
             set
             {
                 SetupSalesTax();
                 salesTax.Id = value.Id;
                 salesTax.UnitPrice = value.UnitPrice;
             }
         }      
        public List<InvoiceLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
        
        private InvoiceLineItem salesTax;

        private void SetupSalesTax()
        {
            if (salesTax is null)
                salesTax = new InvoiceLineItem
                {
                    InvoiceLineItemType = InvoiceLineItemType.SalesTax,
                    Quantity = 1,
                    Description = "Sales Tax",
                };
        }
    }
```

So 2 and 3 relate to the Expense, and 4 relates to Sales Tax.

For 2+3, I can add an InvoiceId property to the InvoiceLineItem - this essentially exposes the shadow property:

```
public class InvoiceLineItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public InvoiceLineItemType LineItemType { get; set; }
    
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    
    public int InvoieId { get; set; }
}
```

For 4, I can simply add the property to the Invoice object, and things magically work.  In the database, EF adds a new SalesTaxId column to the Invoice table (with the foreign key to InvoiceLineItem).  When I create a new Invoice with sales tax, that entity gets saved to the InvoiceLineItem table with a null InvoiceId.  When I retrieve the Invoice, the non-sales tax line items are put into the LineItems collection on the Invoice, and the sales tax line item is put into the SalesTax property on the Invoice (as long as I .Include(i => i.SalesTax)).  Honestly I'm surprised that this works with so little changes.

But these don't work together; when saving to the database, I get errors such as:

"Both relationships between 'InvoiceLineItem' and 'Invoice.InvoiceLineItems' and between 'InvoiceLineItem' and 'Invoice.SalesTax' could use {'InvoiceId'} as the foreign key. To resolve this, configure the foreign key properties explicitly in 'OnModelCreating' on at least one of the relationships."

When attempting to set up the relationship like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
    .HasMany(i => i.InvoiceLineItems)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(li => li.InvoiceId);
```

I get a new column, InvoiceId1, on the InvoiceLineItem table with this warning when generating the migration:

"The foreign key property 'InvoiceLineItem.InvoiceId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'InvoiceId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.
An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data. Please review the migration for accuracy."

I've tried doing each of these first, and then the other second - generating two migrations - but I still get the issue.  And, of course, I've tried them together in a single migration.

Yes, I know this is something that could be classified as a hack.

I could attempt to just have all line items live in the collection, and then have accessors that filter out the non-tax ones for some uses and the sales tax one for others.  I'm trying to avoid this.  I'm also trying to make as few model changes as I can; it's unlikely that I can do a major redesign of the model.  It seems that having an InvoiceLineItem live in two places is causing some grief.

I could also have another hierarchy of entities that point BACK to the line items; something like:

```
public class BaseEntryReference 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLineItemReference : BaseEntryReference
{
    public int InvoiceLineItemId { get; set; }  
}

public class SalesTaxReference : BaseEntryReference 
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; } // I wouldn't have to add the SalesTax to the line items
}

public class ExpenseReference : BaseEntryReference
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }  // I wouldn't have to change the Expense or InvoiceLineItem entities
}
```

These would live in their own table, and I've have reference from BankEntry to EntryReference.  This seems like more work and complexity, though, and I'm trying to avoid that.

So my questions are:

- Can anyone thing of a way to get my first attempts to work?
- Is there another option that I can try?

Sorry this is long, and thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like the root of your issue is that you have a one-to-many relationship between Invoice and InvoiceLineItem, but you want to also have a special one-to-one relationship between Invoice, and a particular InvoiceLineItem for the SalesTax. There are a few ways to go about this, each with their own drawbacks/costs.

Option 1: Reference the specific SalesTax line item. The easiest way to do this would be to have a SalesTaxInvoiceLineItemId in the invoice table/entity. The relationship can then be mapped to use this column to resolve a SalesTax item. This could be required (non-nullable) or optional (nullable) The drawback of this approach is that there is no inherent way in the schema to enforce that the SalesTaxInvoiceLineItemId actually points at an InvoiceLineItemId that is associated with the invoice. For instance you could accidentally link to an InvoiceLineItem that references a completely different Invoice and the database FK constraint would be happy. You would want to ensure a unique constraint is put on SalesTaxInvoiceLineItemId to ensure two invoices don't reference the same SalesTax item.

Option 2: Break SalesTax out of InvoiceLineItem. While it may share the same values of an InvoiceLineItem, it's relationship with an invoice is special. If it doesn't need to be considered alongside other line items it can be broken off completely within its own table, otherwise a joining table.

For example:

```
public class SalesTax
{
     public int Id { get; protected set; } 
     public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
     // .. Insert fields from Line Item that are applicable to a Sales Tax usage, even if all of them.
     public virtual InvoiceLineItem InvoiceLineItem { get; set; } // optional reference if we still need "sales tax" to recorded in the Line Items.
}
```

Bringing the fields into the table is generally a better option because then the values are specific to this invoice. Otherwise the above reference to a line item suffers the same issues as Option 1 where an invoice could be referencing an invoice line item that belongs to a different invoice.

Option 3: Resolve by type. If InvoiceLineItem has a "type" that can identify a SalesTax from other invoice line items against an invoice, an invoice can resolve it's sales tax item using an unmapped property that fetches the sales tax item:

```
[NotMapped]
public InvoiceLineItem SalesTax
{
    get => InvoiceLineItems.First(x => x.InvoiceLineItemType == InvoiceLineItemTypes.SalesTax);
}
```

This solution gets rid of the problem that an invoice pointing at a Sales Tax line item might reference an item that doesn't belong to the invoice, but it comes at the cost that we cannot do things like reference "SalesTax" inside a Linq2Sql query, and would need to eager load invoice line items to get it, or incur a lazy load hit.  If we do want to query across something relating to the sales tax, we need to explicitly do it through InvoiceLineItems I.e.:

```
.Where(x => x.InvoiceLineItems.Where(ili => ili.InvoiceLineItemType == InvoiceLineItemTypes.SalesTax).Select(ili => ili.Amount).FirstOrDefault() ...)
```

... which can get pretty messy to write and guard things like #null checks etc.

Overall I would generally recommend Option #2 breaking Sales Tax into a separate table with fields, and optionally with a reference to a Line Item if needed. If there is still a LineItem record needed for the sales tax then you can have a maintenance job that periodically goes through Sales Tax records, looks up their associated line items and vets that the values and references all match. If it finds a problem, you get a notification and go on the hunt for something allowing them to get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Never fails, figured it out right after I posted.  Three parts to the answer:

- Add an InvoiceLineItem property to Expense
- Add a nullable int SailsTaxId property to Invoice
- Configure the foreign key like this:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
                .HasOne(i => i.SalesTax)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.SalesTaxId);
```

This seems to do everything I need.